# PHPStorm refactor shortcut to give an alias in use statement

Tags: phpstorm

When I try to `use` a class that causes name conflict ie. I have two classes with the same name but different namespaces and I try to use both of them PHPStorm shows a prompt to rename the second class = give it an alias with `as`.

```
<?php
use MyNamespace\SomeClass;
use MyOtherNamespace\SomeClass as SomeOtherClass;
```

I would like to be able to call this prompt any time when pointer is on a class preferably from a keyboard shortcut. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With PhpStorm 2018.3 you can use "Replace with Alias" feature: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/12/new-refactorings-in-phpstorm-2018-3/

[image]

Comment: A side note: the refactoring won't work if "Selected Class is not located inside the project"

Comment: Is there a possibility to save the alias somewhere in the settings, so that every time you type `new BarService()` , the `use Bar\Service as BarService` is automatically added ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use PHPStorm refactoring feature (cursor on *SomeOtherClass*, Shift+F6), it allows to rename alias and its usages.

[click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuJUU.jpg)

If you have already used *SomeClass* in your script without an alias, first you should set an alias with the same name:

```
use MyNamespace\SomeClass as SomeClass;
```

and then refactor this alias, as decribed above.

Another one solution:

> If you import a conflicting name, like Foo\MyClass and you already have use Bar\MyClass; in your document, you should be faced with the following prompt

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| Import class                               |
+--------------------------------------------+
| Alias name:                                |
| [________________________________________] |
|                                            |
| [X] Always create alias while class import |
|                                            |
|                          [ OK ] [ Cancel ] |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

> The trick is to check the "Always create alias" checkbox to always be
>   faced with the prompt while importing.
>
> Forgot to mention that you should also uncheck the settings
>
> Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import > [ ] Enable auto-import in
>   file scope
>
> Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import > [ ] Enable auto-import in
>   namespace scope

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/phpstorm-importing-namespaces-with-aliases/replies/99388

Comment: Please provide sample code or explanation rather than giving links since links can be unreachable in time and make your answer unreliable.